# Save Secured Page as PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I have a page that has a good deal of XHTMl, CSS and Javascript on it, and I need to get a PDF version of it (it is generating a chart on the page along with some text).

All the websites and bookmarklets I have founds don't work on a secured page (understandably).

PDF Generation tools such as tcpdf allow javascript, but I think that throwing in the entire Rafael library + some Javascript is a bit much, though I will do it if necessary.

I am looking for some simple scripts that will turn the page being viewed into a PDF for our users. It can be Flash, Adobe Adobe Air, Microsoft Silverlight, Javascript, PHP or anything of that nature.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Good luck with the JS. I have yet to hear of a renderer which executes JS.

Comment: WebToPDF.NET 2.0 executes all JavaScript before converting to PDF. http://www.tallcomponents.com/webtopdf2.aspx (Disclosure: I work for this company). Not a simple script though but a .NET library.